# Android action bar overlay

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overlay

Is there a way to extend the action bar in android for a single icon like in the image below? I would like to highlight the rightmost action to the user. I know that this might be against the design guidelines.

[image: Example]

Comment: where is your image??

Comment: Embedded in the post. I'm able to see it. http://i.stack.imgur.com/iS45X.png

Comment: I think that is very difficult to create this kind of ActionBar, so why don't you highlight this image with a different color instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tabs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) instead of buttons to get a bar beneath the selected icon. You can add icons to a tab using setIcon() of class ActionBar.Tab.